# How to replace static imports of class constants in OpenRewrite?

Tags: java, openrewrite

I want to replace static imports of class constants with other class constants.

Example:

Original code

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import static javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;

class ControllerClass {
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getHelloWorldJSON(String name) {
        return "{}";
    }
}
```

Expected code

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

class ControllerClass {
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getHelloWorldJSON(String name) {
        return "{}";
    }
}
```

So I don't want to only replace the class type (`javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType` -> `org.springframework.http.MediaType` ) but also the name of the class constant (`APPLICATION_JSON` -> `APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`)

I tried using the OpenRewrite `ChangeType` recipe but that only changed the class type, not the class constant.
I want to execute this replacement in an OpenRewrite recipe as it will be part of a larger migration.

Comment: May a simple "Replace in files" or, more CLI-ish, a bunch of `sed` commands be suitable for the job?

Comment: I would do this using global text replacement in my IDE, but some command based on `find . | xargs sed -i` would work too

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to execute the replacement in an OpenRewrite recipe as it will be part of a larger migration recipe. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I have updated the ticket.

Comment: Hi @VincentBotteman; sorry it took a while to spot your question; we're a little more active on [Slack](https://join.slack.com/t/rewriteoss/shared_invite/zt-nj42n3ea-b~62rIHzb3Vo0E1APKCXEA), but will be monitoring StackOverflow as well. I've logged your question as [a feature request](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/issues/2755), as it seems like a good (and even easy) addition. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Tim The new recipe ReplaceConstantWithAnotherConstant solves my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This has [since been implemented](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/pull/3037), and [documented here](https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/recipes/java/replaceconstantwithanotherconstant). It can be used  with an example `rewrite.yml` file:

```yaml
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: com.yourorg.ReplaceConstantWithAnotherConstantExample
displayName: Replace constant with another constant example
recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.java.ReplaceConstantWithAnotherConstant:
      existingFullyQualifiedConstantName: javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
      fullyQualifiedConstantName: org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

Thanks for the suggestion!